# How to define form and submit button outside a foreach loop, and use arrays for a hidden variables

Tags: php, arrays, loops, cart, hidden-field

I made a command button to take all the produse what a customer select(cart online) and send in the mysql db to record the command, but i face with a problem, when the customer sumbit the CONFIRM BUTTON (to give theirs adrress like a custom dates for the command) the script supposed to take their array items(products selected to buy) and give him a form to type their dates about the command. But is take me only the dates(`prettotal` `produseID` `produseNume` `size`) (only the dates for `totalCOMANDApret` and `cantitate` is showing me well) for the last array items select(last products in the cart) and I dont know how to figured out with this problem....

cart page

```
$i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        // start select query stmt
        $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, size, details FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($idSelect, $product_name, $price, $size, $details);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
        while ($stmt->fetch())    {
           $idSelect;
           $product_name; // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
           $price;    
           $size;
           $details;    
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        // stoop select stmt    
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
                // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="100" height="62" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $price . ' RON</td>';
        // How to split a query value into several mutiple rows for a select tag using explode() STAART SIZE
        $myArraySize = explode(' ',  $size);
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><select name="size">';
        foreach($myArraySize as $my_ArraySize)
        {
        $cartOutput .= '<option  value="'.$my_ArraySize.'">'.$my_ArraySize.'</option>';
        }
        $cartOutput .= '</select><input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />buc
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //STOP SIZE
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $pricetotal . ' RON</center></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
```

cart page with form hidden value

```
$cofirmaComanda = '<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">';
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 

            // ...
            $cofirmaComanda .='
            <input name="prettotal[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
            <input name="produseID[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">
            <input name="produseNume[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
            <input name="size[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
            <input name="cantitate[]"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
            <input name="produse[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $item_id .'">;
            <input name="totalCOMANDApret"  type="hidden" value="'. $cartTotal .'">';
                } 
            $cofirmaComanda .='<input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comandaTOW"></form>';  
        } //close the first loop
```

second page confirm_comanda.php with the get variable

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST["prettotal"]); $i++) {
    $pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"][$i];
    $PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"][$i];
    $produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"][$i];
    $size = $_POST["size"][$i];
    $cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"][$i];
    $total = $_POST["totalCOMANDApret"][$i];
}
```

second form (on page confirm_comanda.php) to take customer dates for valid the command

```
    <form action=""   method="post">
<tr><td>nume: <input name="nume_client" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td>email: <input name="email_client" type="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>telefon: <input name="telefon_client" type="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td>judet: <select name="judet_client">
<option value="Arges">Arges</option>
<option value="Arad">Arad</option>
<option value="Timis">Timis</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>adresa: <input name="adresa_client" type="text"></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="prettotal" value="<?php echo $_POST["prettotal"][$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produseID" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseID'][$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produseNume" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseNume'][$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cantitate" value="<?php echo $_POST['cantitate'][$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'][$i]; ?>">
<tr><td><input  type="submit" name="sumbitDateClienti" value="Trimite Comanda"></td><td><input type="button" onClick="location.href='index.php';" value="Inapoi la Cumparaturi"></td></tr>
</form>
```

on the section is giving me error

> Undefined offset: 2 in E:\wamp\www\MyOnlineStore\cofirma_comanda.php
>   on line 85(means `<input type="hidden" name="prettotal" value="<?php echo $_POST["prettotal"][$i]; ?>">`)

Comment: Show full code how you are using for this `second form (on page confirm_comanda.php) to take customer dates for valid the command`

Comment: ... When you are getting `$pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"][$i];` in `for loop`. Then, why not using this variable (`$pretTotal`), rather than using `value="<?php echo $_POST["prettotal"][$i]; ?>`  ?

Comment: I edited now, showing all the code for second form, but my problems starts when i call the variable in first rows of the pages `confirm_comanda.php`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing multiple values through **cart.php** page. And, accessing directly like `<?php echo $_POST["prettotal"][$i]; ?>`. So, obviously it will throw undefined offset error.

Update it like this way.

**confirm_comanda.php**

```
<form action=""   method="post">
  <tr><td>nume: <input name="nume_client" type="text"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>email: <input name="email_client" type="email"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>telefon: <input name="telefon_client" type="number"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>judet: 
      <select name="judet_client">
        <option value="Arges">Arges</option>
        <option value="Arad">Arad</option>
        <option value="Timis">Timis</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>adresa: <input name="adresa_client" type="text"></td></tr>
  <?php
  for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST["prettotal"]); $i++) {?>
    <input type="hidden" name="prettotal[]" value="<?php echo $_POST["prettotal"][$i]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="produseID[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseID'][$i]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="produseNume[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['produseNume'][$i]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cantitate[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['cantitate'][$i]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'][$i]; ?>">
  <?php }?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="sumbitDateClienti" value="Trimite Comanda"></td><td>
      <input type="button" onClick="location.href='index.php';" value="Inapoi la Cumparaturi">
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

I don't know exact logic behind what you are trying to do with those multiple values, but, there was the mistake which I found.